# Help fixing some of my questions in order to (hopefully) lift the question ban

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, post-ban

I have asked 10 questions in total on Stack Overflow. Of those, 7 are negatively-scored, 2 have scores of 0, and 1 has a positive score. I am now hitting a [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), and I see that what I should do to get out of the question ban is edit and improve my old questions.

The problem is that I don't really know how to improve my old questions. In order to narrow this support request down, I'd like to focus on two specific questions:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338755/why-is-margin-top-or-margin-borrom-not-working-on-this-div)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72829158/how-to-share-a-java-project-with-a-jdbc-and-a-sql-connection)

What can I do to improve these questions? Please provide me with specific, actionable feedback. In doing so, I hope to not only fix these specific questions and hopefully regain my privilege to ask questions, but also learn how to better ask questions on Stack Overflow in general.

Comment: If you *really* want to ask good questions, read this oldie: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/. Now reread your questions, pretend you're some random user on the other side of the globe. Do you understand the questions and are they answerable unambiguously (i.e. without having to fill in blanks) and in a non-opinionated manner?

Comment: Qt1: What is "*(margin-) **borrom***"...!? => Spell-check your Qt's on Typos/Grammar/Punctuation... // Qt2: Is very broad, "*SQL Database*" is a bit vague, which one?, etc..., more details needed... (Already closed as "Needs Focus" actually...) // For all your (5 (still) visible) Qt's, you never followed up / interacted with any Comments/Answers (except 1 Comment), + never accepted any Answer (while 1 Qt even received 4 Answers!), that doesn't really *help* for your (next) Qt's to improve / be well received... No Follow-up on this current Qt on 'Meta' either...

Comment: For some reason, it always stops at ten. Any user I've found who has had the ban always has around 10 questions (including myself). Super odd...

Answer (score 0):

### For question one

Here are some improvements

1. Create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (Cut out a bunch of code)
2. Create a title that would help future users
3. Remove things that aren't useful to the question such as:

> Please have a look.

Why it may have downvotes

1. It's a two parted question (which means there's a high chance of it [getting closed as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423699/should-two-part-questions-be-closed))
2. It seems like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)
3. Your post is mostly code

### For question two

1. This is also a two parted question
2. I don't recommend trying to fix this question, as it is most likely unsalvagable. Try to fix questions with -1 to 2 upvotes.

We're both question banned, so I wish you the best of luck.

I also see that you have a lot of deleted questions that count heavier than non-deleted ones. Try to un-delete as many as you can (the quality ones of course).